# What are !transpiled files and why are my .js files not showing in Chrome Debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript

I am trying to get a web project that uses typescript up and working.

When I use the Chrome debugger (F12 tools), and browse to my source typescript file, I see next to it a file with the same name but with a '!transpiled' on it.

So my `app.ts` has an `app.ts!transpiled` right below it in the list.

However, my project has already transpiled `app.ts` into `app.js`.  But my `app.js` does not show up in the listing of files.

Unless I "Map to system resource files" and then my `app.js` shows up, but it warns me that they are not the same.  (And they are not. They are very close, but not the same.)

**So, what is going on here?  Is Chrome doing is own transpilation?  If so, why?**

Comment: @DouglasLudlow - yes.  But I have since figured that this comes from the frankwallis/plugin-typescript.